# Bigquery connector in python

Tags: google-bigquery

I am evaluating different cloud technologies for my project. I see that aws has python connector as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/python-connect-examples.html

Is there something similar available for google bigquery? I do see an option of service account but that is not the same as python connector, I basically want to provide access to different team member with user id and password access.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe this feature is not available yet for BQ. The closest I can think of is manually creating a credential for the user and authenticating it and calling the API, please see reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed#bigquery_auth_user_flow-python).
Alternatively you can grant access to users pre defined roles by a [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control)( Identity and Access Management) such as users, admin, etc etc.